# Python AWS Lambda spins new connection to RDS for each deployment

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, mysql-python, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I have a python based Lambda function, that connects to MySQL(RDS) database.

Every time I deploy the Lambda code and run the function, a new connection is created.

How can I reuse the same connection or flush the old connections before creating a new one?

Comment: You won't be able to change the new connection creation unless you can keep the lambda function running.  Your lambda function should probably try to close the connections itself.  You might need to do it as a timeout. But try calling `.close` on your connection.

Comment: just close your connection before the function terminates

Answer (score 3):

Close connection inside your lambda function. This is expected and normal behaviour of Lambda.